# SQL database design with multiple page types connected to each other

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures, relationship

I am working on a project where I am going to make a community.

The problem I encounter is the following:

There is going to be 8 different types of pages on the site like "Store", "Event" and "Blog".

Some pages will be owned by a company others will be owned by a user.
Some pages should have the possibility of writing messages to users and other pages (pages that is allowed to send messages to each other).

Users are going to be able to:
1. Follow some page types but not others
2. Like some page types but not others
3. Write a public message on some page types profile page but not others
4. Write personal messages to some page types but not others
5. All users who are administrators on a page are going to get an extra inbox where he/she can read and respond to the pages messages

I have been trying out a lot of different approaches to make this work, but I however I do it I get a LOT of tables where I need to make a LOT of joins which makes me worried about the performance later on.

---

The best solution I have come up with is to make the following tables:

1. Users
2. Pages
3. Stores
4. Events
5. Blogs

And set all page types (users, stores, events, blogs) to own a page.
Then all pages are allowed to message each other.

6. Store_likes
7. Event_followers
8. Blog_followers

to control which page types are allowed to be followed or liked

9. Inboxes

That represents which page inbox belongs to which users

---

Is this the best way of doing it, or do anyone have a better solution?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

/ Elias

Comment: I think you are overloading your DB design. What I mean by that is, why don't you split your design into two: **1)** Basic DB structures (tables) driven by your business rules (e.g. item and comment. So that you can have items and users can make comments on items **without restriction** !) **2)** design your webservice (I am assuming it is a web project because you mentioned PAGES), do apply restrictions on those tables. (e.g. only authorized and resigterered users can make comments on items etc).

Comment: Ye, it feels like i am doing the DB a little bit to complicated.
I am currently studying web development, but we haven't covered any advanced relational databases yet.

Do you mean that I should make the restrictions for which pages are allowed to be followed e.t.c. in the php code and completely skip these restrictions in the DB?

Wouldn't that leave loop holes for hackers?

Comment: If we could implement all business logic at the DB level, we would not need the web app tier. A simple HTML and CSS would do the job. Think about a multitier web application as a distribution of responsibilities. Do avoid piling up all responsibilities on the shoulders of a single tier. Do not design for hackers. Once you complete your application, you can harden up your application and all tools/services/servers etc. you use to run it.

Comment: Use MySQL for data, not business logic.  Use PHP (or whatever) for business logic and formatting, not data.  In the database, think about what Entities (Users, Events, etc) exist and what Relationships (Likes, Permissions, etc) exist between them.  Implement each Entity and each Relationship as a table.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a very general modeling question here which is difficult to answer.  But general my recommendation is to first create a model.  This amounts to deciding what the entities are, what are the primary keys and unique keys and properties of those entities and the relationships that exists between the entities.  For each property decide whether it is required or optional.   For relations between entities decide the cardinality of the relation and the inverse relation.  Create a model first without worrying about performance at first.  Then implement the model in the database.  Your application is very standard. Dont worry about lots of tables and joins.   Most likely it will be OK.